# Using baking soda

Tags: baking-soda

What is baking soda used for, and how much should be added?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  I edited it to clarify, and remove the question about whether or not baking soda has health risks, as we avoid questions of that nature.

Comment: Hey Insha, welcome to Seasoned Advice!  

Your question is very general, though.  Particularly, I don't see that we can answer "how much should be added" unless we know what you're making.

Answer (score 3):

Baking soda is used in cooking for two purposes:

1. [As a leavening agent](https://www.joyofbaking.com/bakingsoda.html), in order to make baked goods rise.  It does this by reacting with acids in the batter or dough, and producing carbon dioxide gas.
2. To soften beans during cooking, [particularly chickpeas](https://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/ottolenghis-chickpea-cooking-method-509519). The alkalinity of the soda helps the complex carbohydrates and fiber in some types of beans break down, allowing them to puree more smoothly.

I can't answer "how much is added" unless I know what you're making.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [King Arthur website](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipe/leaveners.html), 1/4 teaspoon of baking soda is enough to leaven 1 cup of flour.  Baking soda leavens by reacting with acidic ingredients and moisture (plus a little more when heat is added). It begins to lose its leavening effect as soon as it is mixed, so cooking soon is critical.